# Height 100% not working properly while resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I am having Issue in using height . I have used height:100% for a div in my page. And I set a background color for that. It works fine while the browser is maximised. But when it is resized my div is not rendered properly.

My problem is when I resize the browser window , a scroll appears for my div but the background color is not rendered for my whole div. It is rendered only for what portion I have seen when I resize the window.

My styleclass

```
html,body{height:100%;} 
.rightDiv{  height:100%;width: 39%;background: #3F5D91;float: right;color: #F0F0F0;}
```

Plz help me to get out of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you provide your code..that makes us to help you better..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. http://jsfiddle.net/bz8p5/

Comment: Yes... It works fine in jsfiddle.net. But when I am having some inner divs in that., some problem occurs in browser window

Comment: As @Fredsbend said, its fine in jsfiddle. So can you please provide some more details or may be code snippet that will help to figure out the main cause of this.

Comment: If inner divs inside .right div are overflowing it is because the content or the divs themselves are height in px or other absolute value instead of % like the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this using a local html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,body{height:100%;} 
      .rightDiv{height:100%;width: 39%;background: #3F5D91;float: right;color: #F0F0F0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="rightDiv">Hello</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and on Firefox 18.0.2/Windows7 I see the div on the right, coloured blue, and I see a scroll bar when full-screen, or resized.

Scrolling reveals the rest of the div with the background colour intact, so I can't account for why you see that.

However, I'm wondering if you actually want to see the scroll bar. Setting an element to 100% usually means you just want it to fill the viewport, not spill over.
If this is the case, then you need to remove any default margin that the browser applies to elements that contain your div, e.g. the body. Setting:

```
 html,body{margin:0; height:100%;}
```

will make the div fit properly.

Incidentally, sites like [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) offer the option of applying reset style sheets like [Normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) and [Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), and you should watch out for these being pre-selected when you create a new pen/fiddle (JSFiddle does this for Normalize).

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems. Only one thing helped me here. When I needed 100% height for body element I had to set him this styles:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /*makes background cover whole page
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

similar things you can involve to other elements.

Comment: Thanks Anilka for your answer.But -moz-background-size: cover; It is a firefox specific property.Hope it won't work for other browsers.